# How to trace and debug external memory allocations in Android?

Tags: android, memory, java-native-interface, dalvik

I am trying to fix a memory issue in an Android application.

I am convinced that the memory leak is not happening on the internal heap, as I have thoroughly investigated this possibility using the Memory Analyzer Tool, and the Heap/Allocation Tracker in DDMS.

I believe to find the source of the problem, I have to look at the allocations on the external heap, rather than the internal heap.

> 10-05 18:17:06.221: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2559): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1137K, 47% free 4556K/8455K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 6ms+4ms

The external figure is the one that is ballooning out of control before a crash.

Is there a way to do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the MAT tool? It's very useful.

http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

If you're having problems with memory due to Bitmaps, look into WeakReference or make sure to call recycle() on your bitmaps when you're done.

Comment: I have looked into MAT, however it only analyzes data allocations made on the internal heap.  Is there a way to point this tool to the external heap?  Thank you.

Comment: Not that I know of. BUT, most of the troubling allocations are Bitmap's (which are allocated off heap). Is your app dealing with Bitmap at all?